# How to design a matrix function to meet the following conditions

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis

Suppose I have a matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, such that

1. $X$ is symmetric
2. Do not know the rank

I want design a **matrix function** $f(X,Q)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $Q = qq^T$ and $q\in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that

1. $f(X,Q)$ is symmetric
2. $\text{tr} (f(X,Q))=0$
3. rank$(f(X,Q))$ is $2$.

For

1. we can design $QX+XQ$
2. I only know the property $\Omega Q + Q\Omega^T$ with $\Omega$ a skew-symmetric matrix (since tr$(Q\Omega)=q^T\Omega q=0$.
3. Choose $f(X,Q)=QX+XQ$. The basis for its column space is $\{q, Xq\}$, suppose $Xq \neq q$.

However, I have no idea how to combine all of them. Can anyone help me this?

Sincerely appreciate this help.

Comment: (3) is not necessarily true for your example.  The rank could be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: The constant function f(X, Q) = diag(1, -1, 0, ..., 0) satisfies all properties, but it is most likely not what you want, right?

Comment: @A.Z. No. I want it to be in the function of $X$ and $Q$. But still helpful

Comment: @RobertIsrael I will try to put some constraints on it such as $Xq \neq q$.

Comment: @Denny My function **is** a function of $X$ and $Q$. It just does not depend on the arguments.
What do you mean by the term **matrix function**? [Matrix functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function) have a strict definition, which does not immediately fit the form $f(X,Q)$.

Comment: @A.Z. The matrix function here I mean, for example $f(X,Q) = 2X+3Q+4QX$.

Comment: $Xq \ne q$ is not enough.  You need $q$ and $Xq$ to be linearly independent.

Comment: Do you want your function to be a matrix polynomial in $X$ and $Q$, with constant coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no such function

### Assumption on the Function space

I assume that $f$ has to be a polynomial in the variables $X$ and $Q$, i.e., $f$ is a sum of terms of the form

$$
a_k X^{k_1} Q^{k_2} X^{k_3} \dots Q^{k_j}
$$

where $a_k$ is a real/complex number.

$$
f(X,Q) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{\substack{k \text{ is an integer} \\\\ \text{partition of } i}} a_{k} X^{k_1} Q^{k_2} X^{k_3} \dots Q^{k_j}
$$

If this is not the class of functions you had in mind, could you specify further?

### The proof

As there are no restrictions on $X$ and $Q$ the zero matrices are possible choices for $X$ and $Q$ (choose $q$ to be the zero vector for $Q$).
Then all terms of $f$ which involve at least one $X$ or $Q$ are 0.
$$
f(0,0) = a_0 X^0 Q^0 = a_0 \mathbb{I}
$$
with the identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$.
Thus except for the case of $n=2$, $a_0 \neq 0$ the matrix $f(0,0)$ never has rank 2, however in this case $f(0,0)$ does not have trace $0$.

### Alternatives

There are several ways to modify the assumptions to get this to work:

- Restrict the set of matrices $X$ and $Q$ for which the requirements have to hold. Especially, exclude the zero matrices.
- Extend the set of possible functions, to, for example, include the constant function $f(X,Q) = \operatorname{diag}(1, -1, 0, \dots, 0)$.
- Drop one of the requirements.

Comment: I just come up with such possible function. Not sure if it is correct.     $f(X,Q) = XQ-QX$. It is symmetric, rank 2 with $\{Xq, q\}$ if $Xq, \, q$ are L. I. And trace of $f(X,Q)$ is zero since tr$(XQ) = q^TXq$, so tr$(f)=q^TXq-q^TXq=0$.

Comment: If $q$ is the zero vector then $Xq$ and $q$ are not linear independent. Is $q=0$ allowed for your problem?